# Save many-to-many in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I want to show a Teacher and all assigned courses for the teacher in a listbox on edit (Many-to-Many relationship: Course, Teacher, and CourseTeacher). (I want to highlight courses that are already selected, and if user changes selection it will be reflected in the database).

My problem is that it works for Get method, but when I post to update teacher and relevant courses it doesn't do it automatically(updates teacher info, but not selected courses), though it has all of the courses assigned in object.

I'm new to MVC, so I'm not even sure if my models are correct. But I guess the problem is in the post method.(Last piece of code, please see my comments).

To be clear. I already have list of courses avaialble. I just want to associate them with several teachers.

What I've done so far: ViewModel

```
public class TeacherEditor
    {
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedCourseIds { get; set; }
        public MultiSelectList Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

teacher model:

```
 public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

            public Teacher()
          {
              Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
          }
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                     @Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.SelectedCourseIds, Model.Courses)
        </div>
```

Controller GET:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            var teacher = db.Teachers.Include(x=>x.Courses).Where(x=>x.TeacherID==id).SingleOrDefault();
            if (teacher==null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var selectedCourses = teacher.Courses.Select(x=>x.CourseID);
            var model = new TeacherEditor
            {
                Teacher = teacher,
                Courses = new MultiSelectList(db.Courses, "CourseID", "Name", selectedCourses),
                SelectedCourseIds = selectedCourses.ToArray()
            };
            if (model == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Controller POST:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(TeacherEditor teacherEditor)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    foreach (var id in teacherEditor.SelectedCourseIds)
                    {
                        Course course = db.Courses.Where(x=>x.CourseID==id).SingleOrDefault();
                        teacherEditor.Teacher.Courses.Add(course); //Here I'm adding courses back to Teacher object for save.
                    }
                db.Entry(teacherEditor.Teacher).State = EntityState.Modified; /?This doesn't save records to my relationship table. Why?
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(teacherEditor);
        }
```

Comment: your example is involved. seeing if I understand correctly, you attempt to add all selected course back to teacher. how do you account for courses in the list that were already part of the teacher's course list?

Comment: @DaveA, I don't right now. I though that EF is smart enough to skip adding a course if it already exists. I can add a condition before adding, but it still won't save...

Comment: I'm a little out of my depth here. I use EF quite a bit, but I'm far from expert. When I focus on a problem long enough I resolve it. In this case my instinct would be to either attach the existing or ignore them. I would make a call to see if a current course is a member or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't bind on a POST to an interface in MVC (ICollection). The DefaultModelBinder offers no support for binding to abstract base classes and interfaces.  Change `ICollection<Course> Courses` to a concrete implementation like `List<Course> Courses`.

Then you can represent Courses with index notation in your view, ListBoxFor should handle that.

Try something like:

```
public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        public Teacher()
        {
            Courses = new IQueryable<Course>();
        }
    } 

public class TeacherEditor
    {
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedCourseIds { get; set; }
        public List<Course> CourseList 
        {
            get { return Teacher.Courses.ToList(); }
            set { Teacher.Courses = value.ToList(); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer! When I change it to List EF doesn't create relationship table (teacherCourse). Can you show me an example on how to do this correctly?

Comment: @user194076 This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx) might help you. This discusses how to implement many-valued associations in EF.